# "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" does not exist

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

Jenkins gerrit trigger plugins allways throw an exception: "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" does not exist. How can I fixed this problem
My linux distribution is centos7

Answer (score 0):

The Gerrit Trigger plugin is not finding the "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" file.

Go to:

Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Edit

And set the "SSH Keyfile" and "SSH Keyfile Password" fields in the "Gerrit Connections Setting" section correctly. Use the "Test Connection" button to verify if your Gerrit connection is correctly set.